# What is the metadata in clang preprocessed output?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

Using `clang`, the following `test.cpp`:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    x--;
    return x;
}
```

is preprocessed to:

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 342 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "test.cpp" 2

int main() {
 int x = 1;
 x--;
 return x;
}
```

Which has several lines containing `#`+`number`+`string`+`number`.

What do those lines mean?
Is there documentation for this somewhere?